# Adding duplicate Pandas rows that have values flipped

Tags: python, pandas

I know - confusing title. But hear me out.

If I have a pandas DF as such:

```
  date       team opponent
0  20141028      magic  hornets
1  20141028  mavericks    spurs
2  20141029      76ers   pacers
```

And I'd like to create a DF off it where the rows are duplicated but 'team' and 'opponent' values are flipflopped, how would I best do that in pandas?

So i would want this:

```
  date       team opponent
0  20141028      magic  hornets
1  20141028    hornets    magic
2  20141028  mavericks    spurs
3  20141028      spurs mavericks
4  20141029      76ers   pacers
5  20141029     pacers   76ers
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create another dataframe called `df1` with flipped columns, and then append it to `df`.

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1.columns = ['date', 'opponent', 'team']
df.append(df1).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

       date   opponent       team
0  20141028    hornets      magic
1  20141028      magic    hornets
2  20141028      spurs  mavericks
3  20141028  mavericks      spurs
4  20141029     pacers      76ers
5  20141029      76ers     pacers
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't all that elegant, but it gets the job done:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
       date       team opponent
0  20141028      magic  hornets
1  20141028  mavericks    spurs
2  20141029      76ers   pacers
```

Use `loc` for creating a new frame:

```
In [7]: df2 = df.loc[df.index,['date','team','opponent']]
```

Then swap the axis titles:

```
In [8]: df2.columns= ['date','opponent','team']

In [9]: df2
Out[9]:
       date   opponent     team
0  20141028      magic  hornets
1  20141028  mavericks    spurs
2  20141029      76ers   pacers
```

Last, use `pd.concat()` to merge the two frames:

```
In [10]: pd.concat([df, df2])
Out[10]:
       date   opponent       team
0  20141028    hornets      magic
1  20141028      spurs  mavericks
2  20141029     pacers      76ers
0  20141028      magic    hornets
1  20141028  mavericks      spurs
2  20141029      76ers     pacers
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange the columns and then concatenate.

```
df_new = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df[['date', 'opponent', 'team']].values,
                                     columns=['date', 'team', 'opponent'])])
>>> df_new 
       date       team   opponent
0  20141028      magic    hornets
1  20141028  mavericks      spurs
2  20141029      76ers     pacers
0  20141028    hornets      magic
1  20141028      spurs  mavericks
2  20141029     pacers      76ers
```

If you really need the ordering you specified (original pair followed by reversed pair), you can sort it as suggested by @ Jianxun Li:

```
df_new.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```